# What will happened if two dragons of different color try to have a baby?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, dragons

In all d&d books that I had on my hand, nothing mention the progeniture of two dragon of different colors (red and green, silver and gold or even red and gold). Is something say that dragon can only reproduce with a dragon of the same color?

If not, the baby will be only of one color? or an hybrid of the two color? A dragon with no power?

Comment: Is this a [tag:lore] question?

Comment: Is this a duplicate answer rather than a duplicate question? The top voted answer to that question answers this one - but the actual question asked is more specific than this one (which is also asking about chromat-chromat and metal-metal bredding pairs of different colours - not just chromat-metal pairs).

Comment: the answer of the duplicate answer also this question

Comment: Both questions asks about general lore on dragon breeding. They stress different parts of it but both include all combinations and answer there covers all cases. That's why I voted. I hope my vote was helpful.